# Passing MSBuild options when calling devenv

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, devenv

Is there a way to pass command line switches to devenv which are then passed as-is when it calls MSBuild?

Answer (score 4):

You definitely can achieve this for /property (/p) key of msbuild. 
Open .csproj in as text (with notepad.exe): all combinations like $(somename) are properties of msbuild. They can be passed in command line of msbuild via /p:somename=somevalue, but they also can be passed to devenv through environment variable. 
For example: start Visual Studio Command prompt, in the command prompt type:

set semename=somevalue

devenv

Visual Studio will start. Load a solution of your choice, the property "somename" will be passed to all projects in this solution with the value "somevalue".

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm trying to pass the `OutputPath` property but devenv is ignoring it and putting the outputs in the default paths.

Comment: @julealgon: `OutputPath` is not a property of MSBuild. It is not present in the form of $(OutputPath) in the csproj file.

Comment: So how can you make this work with /p? set p=whatever?

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you [call MSBuild directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)?

```
msbuild solution.sln /property:Configuration=Debug
```

Comment: or if you need to build a vdproj